# Dijkstra's Algorithm for doubly linked skip list?

Tags: c++, algorithm, linked-list, dijkstra

So I am having trouble implementing Dijkstra's for my specific program. Here is the current structure I am using as my "nodes":

```
struct Ladders{
    LONG x1;
    LONG y1;
    LONG y2;
    struct Platforms *top;
    struct Platforms *bottom;
};

struct JumpPath{
    double jumpCost;
    int direction;
    bool leftEdge;
    struct Platforms *jumpStart;
    struct Platforms *jumpEnd;
};

struct Platforms{
    LONG x1;
    LONG y1;
    LONG x2;
    LONG y2;
    int index;
    int platNode;
    int id;
    struct Platforms *prev;
    struct Platforms *next;
    struct Ladders *rope;
    std::vector<JumpPath*> jump;
};
std::vector<Platforms*>P;
```

So P is holding all of my platform data in the form of nodes. Each node contains platforms that are connected at the vertices. So in essence, just a doubly linked list. The jump paths and ladders represent a skip to another node, making this a doubly linked skip list. All in all, I am trying to figure out the best way to implement dijkstra's algorithm for my program because I need to save the path as well. The below image is the visualization of the platform data that I am saving into nodes: 
[image: Heres my precalculated node path]

How can I record the path the algorithm would take and should I use another vector to do this? I was also thinking of creating another struct called Edges and keeping all the information like whether it's a jump, cost, and vertices it came from and is going to. The only problem is, I wouldn't know how I would keep track of them in the order of the path.

Comment: That doesn't look anything like a [skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list).

Comment: The image was just a visualization of the node path. The real structure is my platforms struct shown above, it holds all the information on its vertices and also holds the other platforms that are connected to it in the *next and *prev members. The ladder and jump paths represent skips to other platform nodes